# Java process hangs without deadlock or loop

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, dump

My application is quite simple - a scheduler invokes a downloader to download report using MWS API daily. But I am seeing my Java process hangs at some weird point (I can hardly imagine any possibility that it could hang). I have checked the thread dump but no deadlock was found. It would be great if someone can find out the reason. Thanks! Please let me know if any other information is needed.

```
2018-11-29 10:20:33
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode):

"RMI TCP Connection(5)-10.154.27.32" #24 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000053b21800 nid=0x59c8 runnable [0x000000005a5dd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000f9662938> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$37/944290599.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000000f9662a78> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"RMI TCP Connection(idle)" #23 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000053b23800 nid=0xc1c waiting on condition [0x0000000059cbe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fc962b38> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Connection(idle)" #22 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000053b24800 nid=0x55f4 waiting on condition [0x000000005a1bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fc962b38> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"JMX server connection timeout 20" #20 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000053b23000 nid=0x58e4 in Object.wait() [0x0000000054f3e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000fc986458> (a [I)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI Scheduler(0)" #19 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000053b22000 nid=0x58f8 waiting on condition [0x0000000059dee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000fc965e88> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Accept-0" #17 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000053b20800 nid=0x5a50 runnable [0x000000005280e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000fc9682a0> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"myScheduler-1" #15 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000053b1b800 nid=0x5980 runnable [0x0000000058dfd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000fc9bbac0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000fc9bbad0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at com.amazontracker.spaapireport.service.AmazonSpaApiHttpService.issueRequest(AmazonSpaApiHttpService.java:201)
    at com.amazontracker.spaapireport.service.AmazonSpaApiHttpService.get(AmazonSpaApiHttpService.java:83)
    at com.amazontracker.spaapireport.service.AmazonSpaApiReportService.getReport(AmazonSpaApiReportService.java:88)
    at com.amazontracker.spaapireport.downloader.AmazonSpaApiReportDownloader$1.doRetriableJob(AmazonSpaApiReportDownloader.java:199)
    at com.amazontracker.common.runner.RetriableWorkerRunner.run(RetriableWorkerRunner.java:35)
    at com.amazontracker.spaapireport.downloader.AmazonSpaApiReportDownloader.checkStatus(AmazonSpaApiReportDownloader.java:244)
    at com.amazontracker.spaapireport.downloader.AmazonSpaApiReportDownloader.download(AmazonSpaApiReportDownloader.java:123)
    at com.amazontracker.spaapireport.worker.BaseSpaApiDatedDownloadableDataWorker.doDownload(BaseSpaApiDatedDownloadableDataWorker.java:77)
    at com.amazontracker.spaapireport.worker.BaseSpaApiDownloadableDataWorker$1.doRetriableJob(BaseSpaApiDownloadableDataWorker.java:125)
    at com.amazontracker.common.runner.RetriableWorkerRunner.run(RetriableWorkerRunner.java:35)
    at com.amazontracker.spaapireport.worker.BaseSpaApiDownloadableDataWorker.download(BaseSpaApiDownloadableDataWorker.java:157)
    at com.amazontracker.spaapireport.worker.BaseSpaApiDownloadableDataWorker.doJob(BaseSpaApiDownloadableDataWorker.java:70)
    at com.amazontracker.spaapireport.worker.BaseSpaApiDatedDownloadableDataWorker.doJob(BaseSpaApiDatedDownloadableDataWorker.java:50)
    at com.amazontracker.spaapireport.AmazonSpaApiReportImporter$1.doRetriableJob(AmazonSpaApiReportImporter.java:254)
    at com.amazontracker.common.runner.RetriableWorkerRunner.run(RetriableWorkerRunner.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000000fbfd74e8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"Abandoned connection cleanup thread" #14 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000005659e800 nid=0x5860 in Object.wait() [0x0000000056a6f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000fb4947b8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner[713338599:1542708922968]" #13 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000056077800 nid=0x5798 in Object.wait() [0x000000005688e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000fb494968> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"DestroyJavaVM" #11 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000000fe000 nid=0x5a84 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000523ac000 nid=0x5950 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread1" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000523a8000 nid=0x56d8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000005234e000 nid=0x5750 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000005234c800 nid=0x505c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 tid=0x000000005234c000 nid=0x558c runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 tid=0x00000000024cb800 nid=0x5b50 in Object.wait() [0x000000005291f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000faf66320> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000024c9800 nid=0xe44 in Object.wait() [0x00000000526ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000faf664d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000024c1000 nid=0x50fc runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 tid=0x00000000523c5800 nid=0x587c waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 282
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Deadlocks and loops are not the only way for code to appear to hang. It would help if you included the code that was hanging and an indication of where the problem was. A [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be ideal.

Comment: @shmosel I'm trying to find out the reason. I have updated my post. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any classes of yours, so I assume your addition is the "myScheduler-1" thread. It's RUNNABLE ,so in theory it is not stuck, it's just reading a response. It is attempting an SSL handshake, which I would think is fast. Maybe your URL or SSL parameters are wrong. Getting some inspection the HTTPS connection would be helpful, but we don't have enough information to answer the question. Another suggestion I have is to take multiple thread dumps and see if the relevant threads change over time.